# Do all Vim builds use glib?

Tags: vim, glib

My version of non gui Vim seems to use glib.

```
me@laptop:~$ ldd /usr/bin/vim | grep glib-2.0
        libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0xb722c000)
```

But is it possible to build a version of Vim that does not use glib?  If so, what is it using for an event loop?

Comment: Where did your version of non-gui vim come from?

Comment: AFAIK glib is part of gtk but it's not directly related with graphics, it provides lower level facilities.

Comment: @intuited: not sure.  Either its the default that comes with Ubuntu or its from the gvim Ubuntu package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Info from aptitude on Ubuntu's `vim-nox` and `vim-tiny` packages shows that these packages do not depend on glib.

```
$ aptitude show vim-tiny vim-nox | grep glib; echo $?
1
```

The source code contains a [top-level readme file](http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/src/README.txt) which mentions some of the event loops used in the code.  It sounds like there are a few different event loops used, each in a different mode.  They use the function [vgetc](http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/src/getchar.c#1519) to get input.

Comment: thanks!  I just tried `ldd /usr/bin/vim.tiny` and it also shows no glib.